# How to add call a js file in custom module that are added in libraries folder in drupal 7?

Tags: hooks

I am creating a custom module in drupal 7 and adding a js file in sites/all/libraries folder but its not working.Please check my code

```
function mymodule_library(){
$libraries['mymodule'] = array(
    'title' => 'My custom', 
    'website' => 'http://www.test.com/test', 
    'version' => '1.7.14',
    'js' => array(
      'sites/all/libraries/mymod/custom.js' => array(),
    ),
);
return $libraries;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

That code just registers the library with the system. To use it, you need to add it to the page with either

```
drupal_add_library('mymodule', 'mymodule');
```

or as part of a render array:

```
$build['#attached']['library'][] = array('mymodule', 'mymodule');
```

Comment: when I add drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/mymod/custom.js','file');Its work.. After comment .. nothing is working

Comment: @jsh you should not be putting any module under `libraries` directory as it is meant for storing libraries like `js` or `php` the module is needed in order to function. Put your `mymod` module in `sites/all/modules/custom/` to isolate all custom modules from `contrib`. From there you can then add the js like this `drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymod') . '/custom.js', 'file');`.

Comment: Yes I am adding my module under sites/all/module/custom... And require library for this module including here :sites/all/libraries/mymod/custom.js.
but its not working without call this function in .module file:drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/mymod/custom.js','file');

Answer (score 0):

use [drupal_add_js()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

for calling a file ,, your code should be somehting like this:

```
drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/mymod/custom.js','file');
```

Comment: IHMO, it is a bad practice to put the module in `libraries` folder.

Comment: I am not putting module in libraries folder.. just including libraries here.